# Azure Site to Site vpn

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

I am working on azure VPN site to site but i am not able to set a working connection.

[image]

This is what i am working on.

I did created a `Local network gateway` and the `Virtual Network Gateway` and connected them with a `Site to site Ikev2 connection.`

My aim, is to be able to connect from a virtual machine running Windows server (OnPrem) to my virtual machine in the default-subnet.

Following the documentation, which probably i am still confused, i understood that the Local Network Gateway is the Actual VPN device i want to connect to. But the bit, that is confusing me is what IP and address space should i pass there?

I tried to set my computer IP and subnet but i was not able to connect and i tried to set the Virtual machine IP too but i faced the same problem.

Can please somebody help to understand exactly how the local Network Gateway works? I would really appreciate it.

Thank, and please if you need more info just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Local network gateway` is a specific object that represents your on-premises location (the site) for routing purposes

`Local network gateway` object holds properties of your on-premise network like `Static Public IP Address` of your router and `Local Networks`

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal#LocalNetworkGateway